# Reading a value from a file into a variable in shell

Tags: shell, csh

I need to read a value from a file in the following manner.

input log file:

> **some log report data**
>   **no_of_count = "45"**
>   **some log report data**

Now i want to read the line **no_of_count = "45"** into shell script and get that **45** into a variable
Is there any command to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

awk one-liner:

```
awk -F '[ ="]+' '$1=="no_of_count"{print $2}' file
45
```

**Explanation:** This awk uses regex in field separator as space OR `=` OR double quote. `+` quantifier in regex means 1 or more which makes awk to grab more than one of those characters as separators thus printing 45 in `$2`.

Comment: can you elaborate.i mean can you explain

Answer (score 1):

```
var=$(awk -F'=' '/no_of_count/ {print $2}')
```

Comment: This is `sh`, not `csh`.